# Converting a single XML bracket column to multiple columns in T-SQL SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

I've seen similar questions to mine but the XML format has always been different, as the XML format I have does not follow the "standard" strcuture. My table looks like the following (single column with XML bracket as row values):

```
|VAL|
|<person name="bob" age="22" city="new york" occupation="student"></person>|
|<person name="bob" age="22" city="new york" occupation="student"></person>|
```

And the outcome I'm looking for is:

```
|Name|age|city    |occupation|
|bob |22 |new york|student   |
|bob |22 |new york|student   |
```

I can create hardcoded script with these column names, but the problem is that I have over 20 tables that would then all require a custom script. My thinking is that there is a way where I can dynamically, taken into account destination table and a source table (xml), I could have a procedure where this data is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not all clear...

As far as I understand, you have a variety of **different** XMLs and you want to read them generically. If this is true, I'd suggest for your next question, to reflect this in your sample data.

One general statement is: There is no way around dynamically created statements, in cases, where you want to set the **descriptive** elements of a resultset (in this case: the names of the columns) dynamically. T-SQL relies on some things you **must know in advance**.

Try this:

I set up a *mockup scenario* to simulate your issue (please try to do this yourself in your next question):

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Descr VARCHAR(100), VAL XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('One person',N'|<person name="bob" age="22" city="new york" occupation="student"></person>')
,('One more person','<person name="bob" age="22" city="new york" occupation="student"></person>')
,('One country','<country name="Germany" capital="Berlin" continent="Europe"></country>');
```

--this query relies on all possible attributes known in advance.
--common attributes, like the `name`, are returned for a person and for a country
--differing attributes return as NULL.
--One advantage might be, that you can use a specific datatype if appropriate.

```sql
SELECT t.ID 
      ,t.Descr
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [name] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@age)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [age] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@city)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [city] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@occupation)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [occupation] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@city)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [city] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@capital)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [capital] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@continent)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [continent] 
FROM @tbl t;
```

--This query returns as classical EAV (entity-attribute-value) list
--In this result you get each attribute on its own line

```
SELECT t.ID 
      ,t.Descr
      ,A.attrs.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS AttrName
      ,A.attrs.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS AttrValue
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY t.VAL.nodes('/*[1]/@*') A(attrs);
```

Both approaches might be *generated* as a statement on string-level and then executed by `EXEC()` or `sp_executesql`.

Hint: One approach might be to insert the EAV list into a tolerant staging table and proceed from there with *conditional aggregation*, `PIVOT` or hardcoded VIEWs.

### Dynamic approach

In order to read the `<person>` elements we would need this:

```
SELECT t.ID 
      ,t.Descr
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [name] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@age)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [age] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@city)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [city] 
      ,t.VAL.value('(/*[1]/@occupation)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [occupation] 
FROM @tbl t
WHERE VAL.value('local-name(/*[1])','varchar(100)')='person';
```

All we have to do is to **generate** the changing part:

Try this:

A new *mockup* with a real table

```
CREATE TABLE SimulateYourTable(ID INT IDENTITY, Descr VARCHAR(100), VAL XML);
INSERT INTO SimulateYourTable VALUES
 ('One person',N'|<person name="bob" age="22" city="new york" occupation="student"></person>')
,('One more person','<person name="bob" age="22" city="new york" occupation="student"></person>')
,('One country','<country name="Germany" capital="Berlin" continent="Europe"></country>');
```

--Filter for `<person>` entities

```
DECLARE @entityName NVARCHAR(100)='person';
```

--This is a string representing the command

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT t.ID 
      ,t.Descr
      ***columns here***
FROM SimulateYourTable t
WHERE VAL.value(''local-name(/*[1])'',''varchar(100)'')=''***name here***''';
```

--with this we can create all the columns
--Hint: With SQL Server 2017+ there is `STRING_AGG()` - much simpler!

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT CONCAT(',t.VAL.value(''(/*[1]/@',Attrib.[name],')[1]'',''nvarchar(max)'') AS ',QUOTENAME(Attrib.[name]))
    FROM SimulateYourTable t
    CROSS APPLY t.VAL.nodes('//@*') AllAttrs(a)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')) Attrib([name])
    WHERE VAL.value('local-name(/*[1])','varchar(100)')=@entityName
    GROUP BY Attrib.[name]
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','nvarchar(max)');
```

--Now we stuff this into our command

```
SET @cmd=REPLACE(@cmd,'***columns here***',@columns);
SET @cmd=REPLACE(@cmd,'***name here***',@entityName);
```

--This is the command.
--Hint: You might use this to create physical VIEWs without the need to type them in...

```
PRINT @cmd;
```

You can use `EXEC(@cmd)` to execute this dynamic SQL and check the result.

Comment: I'm in the EAV camp.   So many think it is evil.   Sometimes it is the prudent choice

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Sorry my question was unclear. The idea is that I have 50 XMLs with different fields (i.e. city, capital, continent etc.) and all of them need to be written to a SQL table, but it seems like you understood the problem. Are you saying that I have to create a separate query for each table? I'm still testing the solution so apologies for not accepting the answer just quite yet.

Comment: @Anton, If you have to write a *separate query for each table* depends on your needs... The EAV approach might be sufficient... But if you want a **specific resultset** with **dyamically named columns** you will need a **specific query**. If you have to **type** this query depends on your needs again :-). All this can be analysed and generated for each and any case completely dynamically. if you have a known set of structures I'd tend to create the EAV as staging table and specific VIEWs above this table.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you for the word *prudent*. I implemented this term into my active vocabulary now :-)

Comment: Hi ok, did I understand correctly that your approach would be: create a very sparse table with EAV, and then write a view selects relevant column, for relevant table, & filters out empty rows?

Comment: @Anton And again it depends on your nees and the data. You might use `SPARSE` columns for the staging table to reduce the needed space... You can use a query as my first approach, but one for each kind of XML and read the data whenever you need it directly from the XML. How often do you need this? Is this changing data? How many rows? How many common columns? And a lot of more questions...

Comment: Right, will need to answer these questions.. In your original question, the 2nd recommended solution, is it possible to generate this without the cross apply? So that I would have column names as "name,city,country" etc.. and with their respective values?